# Probability question on selecting the same faces of a cube

Tags: probability

I have this question: Two faces of a cube are randomly selected. What is the probability that they are opposite faces? My reasoning here is that I make the first choice of selecting a random face and there are 6 of them, so the probability of selecting any side is 1/6. After my initial choice, I am left with 5 of the faces and only 1 of them will be opposite to the one I chose initially, hence the probability of chosing the opposite side will be 1/5. Now I can find the required probability by multiplying the two values. However, for some reason I get a feeling that my reasoning is not correct and I am missing something, however I cannot think of anything else at the moment. I would appreciate any hints or confirmation of my method!

Comment: Your problem statement is not clear.  The assertion that two faces are "randomly selected" does not convey that they are distinct.   You might mean that they are chosen in a way that makes them distinct, and if so it should be said in the problem setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right to question your reasoning. The first choice is free. Then the probability of choosing the opposite face is $1/5$. You don't multiply that by $1/6$.

A  way to understand your error is to note that you have calculated the probability of $1/30$ for a pair of opposite faces chosen with a particular face chosen first. But there are six possible first choices, so the answer is $6 \times (1/30) = 1/5$.

Another way to see this is to note that there are $6\times 5/2 = 15$ *pairs* of faces. Of those $15$ exactly $3$ consist of opposite faces, so the probability you want is $3/15 = 1/5$.